# best way to search for a string in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, duplicates

I am adding the data that I get from a URL to the array **crops**. After this I am checking for duplicate crops with the help of a new array **cropsSoFar**.

```
     var crops=[];

     for(int i=0; i<results.length;i++)
     {
         var terrains= results.features[i].attributes.Terrain_Id;
        var rawDataOfTerrain=getjsondata("http://or.org");

         var trsetdata= jQuery.parseJSON(tersetjson).d.results;

         crops.push(trsetdata); 
     }

         var cropsSoFar= [];

         for(int i=0; i<crops.length;i++)
         {
             var crop= crops[i];
             if(crop in cropsSoFar)
             {
                 crops.pop(crop);
             }
             cropsSoFar.push(crops[i]);

         }

         if(crops.length!=1)
             alert("Please select terrains with the same crop");
```

Is this the right way to search for a **string** in an **array**? If so, is there is an easier way? If not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: If trsetdata is in string then it will check only one element. and You are checking in empty array of var cropsSoFar= [];.

Comment: No, the `in` operator is certainly the wrong way.

Comment: You have misunderstood the use of array `.pop()`, it takes no argument and always removes the last item of the array. It should be enough to move the `corpsSoFar.push()` into the if-statement and change it to a *not* but it's better to simply check before you push to the first array and skip the second part.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for duplicates on the first creation of `crops` with `indexOf`.

```
var crops = [];

for( int i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
    var terrains = results.features[i].attributes.Terrain_Id;
    var rawDataOfTerrain =getjsondata("http://or.org");
    var trsetdata = $.parseJSON(tersetjson).d.results;

    if( crops.indexOf(trsetdata) === -1 )
        crops.push(trsetdata); 
 }

 if( crops.length != 1 )
      alert("Please select terrains with the same crop");
```

Comment: Just 1 catch. This will store 1st value. If latest value is expected, I'd suggest using object instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a simple string array, than use `Array.prototype.indexOf` as appear in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var list = ["my", "simple", "strings", "array"];
var founds = [];
var i = list.indexOf("simple");

if (i != -1)
   founds.push(list[i]);
```

If what you want to do, instead, is filter the list, you should use the `Array.prototype.filter`, that get a callback function as parameter and returns to you the new array:

```
function getMyStrings(value) {
  return value.match(/m/);
}

var filtered = ["my", "simple", "strings", "array"].filter(getMyStrings);
```

If you have only one result, you could use `find` method. It takes a callback but it get just one value.

The advantage to pass a callback function is that you could easily handle complex objects instead plain strings.